# How to upload and save image in MySQL via SpringBoot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, file-upload

I'm trying to upload and save an image in MySQL with SpringBoot using JPA but unfortunately I'm greeted with this error, can anyone tell me what am I missing ?

Error

```
    Field error in object 'institution' on field 'logo': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@387c2996]; codes [typeMismatch.institution.logo,typeMismatch.logo,typeMismatch.[Ljava.lang.Byte;,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [institution.logo,logo]; arguments []; default message [logo]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.Byte[]' for property 'logo'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.Byte' for property 'logo[0]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile']]
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Entity

```
    @Lob
    private Byte[] logo;
```

controller

```
    @PostMapping("/institutionAddNew")
    public String addNewComp(@ModelAttribute("institution") Institution institution, Model model, 
             HttpSession session,
            @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile fileUpload) throws Exception {
          
        Integer insId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("instId");
        
        Byte[] byteObjects = new Byte[fileUpload.getBytes().length];
        int i = 0;
        for (byte b : fileUpload.getBytes()){
            byteObjects[i++] = b;
        }
        institution.setLogo(byteObjects);
        
        cs.addNewInstitution(institution);
        model.addAttribute("institutionlist", cs.getAllInstitutions(insId));
        return "redirect:/showAllInstitutions";
}
```

Form

```
    <form:form action="/institutionAddNew" method="post" modelAttribute="institution"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <form:input path="instName" />
        <input type="file" name="logo" />

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve it eventually, I had to change the code. I'm sure there are many ways of doing this, not sure if this approached is the best one but it works for me.

Entity

```
private Integer instId;
private String fileName;
private String fileType;
@Lob
private byte[] image;       
public Institution(Integer instId, String instName, String fileName, String fileType, byte[] image) {
    super();
    this.instId = instId;
    this.instName = instName;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.fileType = fileType;
    this.image = image;
}
```

Service

```
public Institution storeFile(Integer instId, String name, MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    
    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
    try {
        Institution institution = new Institution(instId, name,fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes());
        return comrepos.save(institution);
        
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new Exception("Could not store file " + fileName, e);
    }
}
```

controller

```
@PostMapping("/institutionAddNew")
public String uploadImage(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file, 
        @RequestParam("instName") String name, 
        @RequestParam("instId") Integer instId) {
    
    try {
        iservice.storeFile(instId,name,file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/showAllInstitutions";
}
```

Form

```
<form:form action="/institutionAddNew" method="post" modelAttribute="institution"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <form:input path="instName" />
    <input type="file" name="logo" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided information is insufficient to properly diagnose the problem. You need to provide more information.

But I am guessing that, when the `jsp` file is sending data to your controller, it is sending the file as a `MultiPartFile`. But your application is trying to cast it to an `byte` array. That's why your are getting the exception. The problem does not lie with`JPA`, the exception should happen before the data enters the controller.

You can use an `dto` object to pass the data to your controller where the file is a `Multipartfile` object, then you can prepare the `entity` object with the dto object data. Here you can read the `multipartfile` and convert it to an `byte` array and then save it to your database.

Add another `InstitutionParam` class like

```
public class InstitutionParam {
    private MultipartFile logo;
}
```

Keep your Institution class same. Your controller should look like

```
    @PostMapping("/institutionAddNew")
    public String addNewComp(@ModelAttribute("institution") InstitutionParam institution, Model model,
                             HttpSession session) throws Exception {

        Integer insId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("instId");
        MultipartFile fileUpload = institution.getLogo();

        Byte[] byteObjects = new Byte[fileUpload.getBytes().length];
        int i = 0;
        for (byte b : fileUpload.getBytes()){
            byteObjects[i++] = b;
        }
        Institution entity = new Institution();
        entity.setLogo(byteObjects);
        
        // save to db

        cs.addNewInstitution(institution);
        model.addAttribute("institutionlist", cs.getAllInstitutions(insId));
        return "redirect:/showAllInstitutions";
    }
```

Comment: What else would you need ?

Comment: If you can give the stacktrace and the line where the exception happens, it will help to find out the cause. Btw, have you tried my suggestion ?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion without any success and also the above code it doesn't compile I have turned and twisted it accordingly.